# IsolatedStorageException was Unhandled:Operation not premitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

[image]

I'm developing a simple app for Windows Phone using SDK 7.1, and I'm getting the error

> IsolatedStorageException was Unhandled:Operation not premitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream

within `MainPage.xaml.cs`

*Code Snippet:*

> private void btnRd_file_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
>
> ```
>    {
>
>        IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
>
>        IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = ISF.OpenFile("pwd1.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
>
>       using (StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS))
> ```

while trying to Run the application on Windows Phone Emulator.

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots. Just post code here (in a question), and also post full exception message and StackTrace too. See how others do (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12962388/assigning-ienumerable-covariance)

Comment: Nothing wrong with a screenshot, that's why the insert image button exists.

Comment: make sure file build type is set to content or if its resource use a proper path for referencing the file.

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error if the file does not exist.
You should check to see if it exists first.

Answer (score 0):

There can be more than one issue due to which this type of error occurs.
In ur case u are opening the file in read mode which means file must exist at the given path before executing

> IsolatedStorageFileStream FS = ISF.OpenFile("pwd1.txt", FileMode.Open,
>   FileAccess.Read);

line of code.

And if file is exists at given path and u still facing this error. Than see whether u have opened this file before somewhere in code and forget to close the stream using dispose or using statement.

This type of problem also occurs when u already opened the file with and forget to close/dispose it.

**Note:** IsolatedStorageFileStream doesn't provide the exact/helpful information about the original core of error, so developer must debug and see values of variables and objects to get the core of issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the codes for which it is giving the exception in the try catch block

eg.

```
try {
  ..your code..
}
catch { ... code to handle exception ... }
```

The above changes will handle all the possible exception.